# "Don't say it, if you don't want to" in Japanese

Tags: conjugations

Don't say it, if you don't want to.

You don't have to say it, if you don't want to.

How do I convey these in Japanese correctly?

My idea is 言えないこと言ってないもいいです。

But I am really confused by verb conjugation here.

Don't say it = iwanai? ienai?

Don't want to say = ienai? But then it would mean 'I can't say'....

Could you please help in both translation and explanation for these two conjugation forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 言いたくないなら、言わなくてもいい 
>   *lit.* If you don't want to say it, you don't have to say it.

Some comments:

- The "don't have to"-form is ~て+もいい, i.e. you have to form the ~て form of the i-adjective 言わない, which is the correct negative for the verb (and not 言ってない).
- The English leaves out the verb the second time, which can't be done in Japanese.
- なら is just one option for "if" (which I think fits best). Other ways to say it would be

  > 言いたくなければ、…
  >   言いたくなかったら、…
- 言えない means indeed "can't say" Your (slightly corrected) sentence means

  > 言えないことを言わなくてもいい
  >   Things you can't say, you don't have to say.

Comment: "言わない" is not an adjective but 言う verb 未然形 + ない 助動詞. "言わなく" would be 言う verb 未然形 + ない 助動詞 連用形.

Comment: I think i get it now! 説明ありがとうございます！